# Upgrading phpmyadmin 2.11.11.3 to 3.x on CentOS 5.6

Tags: centos, centos5

With php 5.4 coming out, and the mysql extension being depreciated (and possibly becoming obsolete in php 6) I want to make sure I upgrade phpmyadmin, so my error logs aren't filled with depreciation notices just because it uses the old extension.

If anyone can write up a quick tutorial or send me to a link that shows me how to do it, I would appreciate it thoroughly. I've been searching google for a couple days looking for a good write up, but they all seem to assume that I have cPanel or some other third party software that would help me through it. My linux skills aren't exceptional, so please keep that in mind when you answer. If you assume that I'm a moron... I won't get offended. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The PMA wiki has an [upgrade guide](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Upgrading).